# Foundation top bar toggle not working

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

My code is here:

http://ivanabilic.mixture.io/nnb/

The top bar adjusts to a dropdown when under 940px, but the toggle does not work at that point. I initialise the topbar script in the footer, but I don't know how to fix this. I think it's a problem with my CSS, but not sure how.

Help? Thanks!

EDIT: This is the navbar code specifically:

```
    <div class="nav-background">
    <div class="row" id="top">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                    <nav class="top-bar">
                            <ul>
                            <li class="name"><h1><a href="#"><img src="{{ "public/images/logo.png" | root_asset }}" alt="PlusDigital"></a></h1></li>
                            <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <section>
                            <ul class="right">
                            <li class="active"><a class="home" href="#">
                            <img class="home-icon" src="{{ "public/images/home-icon.png" | root_asset }}" alt="Home"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Plans &amp; Pricing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Agency Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </section>
                    </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the initialise of the Javascript:

```
    <script src="/public/scripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).foundationTopBar();</script>
```

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem and post relevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the failed resource errors you have:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/mixture-projects/1286/nnb/public/styles/app.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/mixture-projects/1286/nnb/public/scripts/app.js
```

As far as I am aware you need these two as well. 
See whether the link is correct and/or this is the correct server.

**EDIT:** 
According to [Foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.php)

*All of our plugins and the necessary Javascript to make Foundation work properly. The most important file here is `app.js`, which is used to initialize the various plugins that you might want to use.*

You can find an example of the suggested HTML markup structure further down the page.

Comment: Those files were unnecessary and I've removed them along with the links to them, and it still doesn't work?

Comment: Apparently it was a CSS problem. I'm not including app.js, but foundation.js. It was a CSS rule that had broken it, it was just a case of removing that. But thanks!

Comment: @imcconnell: And what was that rule?

Comment: @imcconnell What was the CSS rule that was causing the Conflict?